# CUDA: parallelizing a multiple nested for-loop having a function call with nested loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, cuda

**Issue**

I am interested in parallelizing a problem using `CUDA`. The `C` code in question follows this simplified form:

```
 int A, B, C; // 100 < A,B,C,D < 1,000

 float* v1, v2, v3;   
 //v1,v2, v3 will have respective size A,B,C
 //and will not be empty

 float*** t1, t2, t3; 
 //t1,t2,t3 will eventually have the size (ci,cj,ck)
 //and will not be empty

 int i, j , k, l;      

 float xi, xj, xk;

 for (i=0; i<A; ++i){   
   xi = ci - v1[i];
   for (j=0; j<B; ++j){
     xj = (j*cj)*cos(j*M_PI/180);   
     for (k=0;k<C; ++k){
       xk = xj - v3[k];
       if (xk < xi){
         call_1(t1[i], v1, t2[i], &t3[i][j][k]);
       }
       else t3[i][j][k] = some_number;
     }   
   } 
 }
```

here `call_1` is

```
void call_1 (float **w, float *x, float **y, float *z){
 int k, max = some_value;
 float *v; //initialize to have size max
 for (k=0; k<max; ++k)
    call_2(x[k], y[k], max, &v[k]);
 call_2(y, v, max, z);
}
```

here `call_2`is

`void call_2 (float *w, float*x, int y, double *z)`

that simply contains operations such as *bit shifting, multiplication, subtraction and addition* inside a single `while` loop.

**Ideas attempted**

So far, my idea is that, the function `call_1`may be transformed into a kernel code `__global__ void call_1`; and that `call_2` may be transformed into device code without modifying its contents. In particular, I can probably make `__global__ void call_1` to be

```
double* v; //initialize to have size max

int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
for (int k=index; k<max; k += stride)
    call_2 (x[k], y[k], max, &v[k]);

__syncthreads();

call_2 (y, v, max, z);
free (v);
```

I'm partly aware that the for loops can be removed by using a combination of `threadIdx, blockIdx, and gridDim`, but I specifically am not sure how *especially that the problem contains a function call that also uses a function call.*

Answer (score -2):

Well there are two possible answers to that, and, while I don't have the courage to search all of it for you, I'll still make it an answer since you seem to have been blatantly ignored. :/

**First.**
Recent CUDA API and nvidia architectures have support for function calls and even recursion in CUDA. I'm not exactly sure how it works as I never used it myself, but you might want to research that. (Or do some Vulkan since it looks like so much fun and also supports it.)

Might help you: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/493567/cuda-programming-and-performance/calling-external-kernel-from-cuda/ 
And other stuff with related keywords. : D
**On the other hand..**
When resolving simple issues, especially if, like me, you would rather spend your time programming than doing research and learning some random API by heart, you can always go with more primitive solutions using only the basic of the language you are using.

In your case, I would simply inline the calls to the function to make a single CUDA kernel, since it seems pretty easy to do.

Yeah, right, it might include some copy-pasting if there are multiple calls to the function... which doesn't really matter if it can make you take it easy and efficiently solve a simple issue and go make something more productive.

```
int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
for (int k=index; k<max; k += stride)
    call_2 (x[k], y[k], max, &v[k]); // Insert call_2 code here instead.
```

Another way to go around that, when you are confident your data is big enough to have a good increase in performances even with the passing of code and data from CPU and RAM to GPU, is to simply have multiple "waves" of cuda kernel call.

You let the first wave process while preparing for the second one, which is then launched on the finished first wave.

It's basically equivalent to other smarter constructs offered by recent CUDA implementations, so you would probably find smarter things to do with a bit of research, but then again... depends on your priority.

But yeah, manually inlining functions is great. : D
*mostly never, but it can be pretty handy

Comment: thanks for your input! I may try to remove the function calls and make the code longer, but that is when I get too desperate. So far I am doing simple progressions on my problem by first converting high dimensional pointers to 1D. However, I haven't found a reliable solution for this case in which I can share here.